# Extra padding on right of the scrollbar on gnome terminal when in vanilla session

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, gtk3, scrollbar

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10. Installed vanilla-gnome-session for default gnome experience. But the problem is the terminal windows has this extra spaces at the right side of scrollbar in adwaita theme. Yaru theme has no problems.

Here is a screenshot

[image: screenshot of extra padding after scrollbar]

I've checked and confirmed that this space is not there in Fedora's version of gnome. What Ubuntu has changed here? What I need to revert? Looks like default gnome experience is not for Ubuntu users.

#### Update

Looks like the problem is in the border color of the scrollbar which is white, contradicting with black borders around the terminal in light theme. When the theme is changed to dark, the problem is gone. So this is about setting consistent border color with the rest of the theme.

#### Update 2

This code in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk-3.css` somewhat fixed the problem in light theme but then creates problem in adwaita dark theme

```
scrollbar {
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.4);
  border-right: 0.4px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
```

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/3.34.1+git20191024-1ubuntu1~19.10.1 This says there are some changes in scrollbar which affects themes

Comment: Filed a bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1865326 . Please verify and click on "affect me too"